# What do you think is the most beautiful thing about WCF?

Tags: wcf, wcf-binding, wcf-client, wcf-behaviour

Does WCF make your life easier or harder? Do you think it's beautiful in nature or should you avoid its ugliness like the plague?

- I like the idea of supporting REST + SOAP interfaces with <s>simple</s> binding configurations (*ala webHttpEndpoint / basicHttpBinding*). I do miss the ASMX days, but SVC seems like it's here to stay.
- WCF + MVC are also great combination to build host factories and custom service routing (*ala ServiceHostFactory / WebServiceHostFactory*).

What are your likes / dislikes?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

WCF makes life much easier:

- **decouples the service** (implementation) from all binding-related stuff - you just write your service to implement the contract, that's all - doesn't need to know anything about which binding / protocol will be used
- **extreme flexibility** with the configuration system, the ability to mix+match your binding/protocol needs
- **extreme extensibility** by providing lots of hooks and points to extend & modify WCF; if you don't like the default behavior. You can create behaviors, bindings, filters - you name it.